# Bootstrap Table sort by date dd/mm/yyy

Tags: bootstrap-table

i have a column with dates in dd/mm/yyyy format (Bootstrap Table)

```
<th data-field="modified" data-sortable="true">Date</th>
```

Like:

```
02/03/2020
10/04/2020
09/07/2019
01/07/2018
```

but sorting occurs not by the entire date, but only by the first digit (day)

```
01/07/2018
02/03/2020
09/07/2019
10/04/2020
```

i found data-sorter parameter with jquery function for it:

```
<th data-field="modified" data-sortable="true" data-sorter="starsSorter">Date</th>

function starsSorter(a, b) {
  if (new Date(a.toDate()) < new Date(b.toDate())) return 1;
  if (new Date(a.toDate()) > new Date(b.toDate())) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

But it dorsn't work:(

Help me, please:)

Comment: Maybe the sorter function needs to be defined before you can refer to it? Just guessing, though.

Comment: tried. the same:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its quite simple, you try to call the `toDate` function on a string.
The parameters `a` and `b` are strings (the dates as string).

This works fine:

```
function starsSorter(a, b) {
  if (new Date(a) > new Date(b)) return 1;
  if (new Date(a) < new Date(b)) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

Here you can test it: https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/UtechtDustin/4216

Answer (score 0):

Or print data as date timestamp for sorting, e.g. in django:

```
<td data-value="{{ transaction.date|date:"U" }}">{{ transaction.date }}</td>
```